# Update PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Estou com uma dúvida, um cliente informou que houve um erro no cadastro dos produtos dele, e os funcionários cadastraram o preço de custo como preço praticado e vice versa.

Teria como eu rodar um update pelo *PostgreSQL*, alterando os preços de custo para preço praticado?

---

Na verdade é o contrário, tenho que pegar o Preço de custo, e inserir no preço 
a coluna vlpreco é a que tem que ser inserida na coluna clprecoant

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se entendi bem deseja pegar o valor contido no atributo preço praticado e inserir no atributo preço de custo e em seguida deletar o atributo do preço praticado. correto? Se for isto poste uma imagem da estrutura da tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Desse jeito*:

```
update NomeDaTabela as s set valor1= p.valor2, valor2= p.valor1 from NomeDaTabela as p where s.valor2=p.valor2;
```

*fazer as correcoes de acordo com sua tabela.